# Start a MAMP server with Grunt.js

Tags: workflow, gruntjs, mamp, yeoman

I want to set my Grunt.js file to launch my MAMP server on `grunt serve`.

I have been trying to use this tutorial here to do this:

https://coderwall.com/p/kwne-g

I was then planning to use this tutorial to set up `grunt watch`:

http://darrenhall.info/development/yeoman-and-mamp

Now I am having trouble with step one. I have successfully installed **grunt exec**. However, `grunt` claims not to be able to find the task 'serverup'.

Here is my code:

```
 grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'serverup',
        'watch',
        'serverdown'
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the examples at the link, it looks like your targets should be `exec:serverup` and `exec:serverdown` for the tasks to work.

The problem here and with many other Grunt related questions is that without the full Gruntfile, "answers" are largely guesses.  Configuration, task loading, and task registration are all related and without seeing all three, it is difficult to say "this is the answer".

Given that, here's a checklist I use for problems like this when using Grunt and packages from NPM:

1. Is the code that supports the task installed?  Did I forget `npm install`? Did I miss
   errors on install (check `npm-debug.log` if it exists)?
2. Have I correctly used `grunt.loadNpmTasks` for the plugin? Is the line in my Gruntfile and 
   did I get the plugin name spelled correctly? Did I or my IDE accidentally use to
   `grunt.loadTasks` when I need `loadNpmTasks`?
3. Have I correctly named/used `grunt.registerTask` for the task? If I need to call a
   specific target for a task, do I have the the name correctly specified?
4. If there are paths involved and things are broken, do I have my [globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) correctly specified?  If a `cwd`
   is involved, do I have the other paths or files correctly specified?
5. Did I get the configuration right? (This is where things get too plugin-specific for a 
   checklist.)

Comment: You were right about exec: needing to be before the commands now I have added that I am receiving a new error, please refer to above gist for full error.

Comment: Been awhile since I used MAMP but try this: http://eightnoneone.com/2012/05/04/run-mamp-as-standard-user/